# GPU skinning issue with GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, gpu

I been working with openGL for a few months now just learning it all on my own. Now I've gotten to render position, texture coordinate models

I am trying to work with animated models which I'll do an animation skinning process on the graphics card.

By the way if someone wants to help me 1 on 1 let me know I wouldn't mind even more direct approach.

Here is my vertex format

```
struct VERTEX_ANIMATED
{
    float3 position;
    float3 normal;
    float2 texCoord;
    float weights[4];
    unsigned boneIndices[4];
};
```

this is how I add my verts to the gpu buffer handle (any uninitialized variables in these functions are located in the ".h" )

```
bool CVertexBuffer::IncreaseVerts( const unsigned int uiNumVerts )
{
    //create our increase by value
    unsigned uiIncrement = (uiNumVerts / BUFFER_INCREASE_SIZE) * BUFFER_INCREASE_SIZE + BUFFER_INCREASE_SIZE;
    m_uiNumVerts += uiIncrement;

    //bind to our buffer
    void* buffer1; 
    if (GLEW_ARB_vertex_shader)
    {
        glBindBufferARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, m_uiVertBufferHandle );

        //make sure our buffer exists
        buffer1 = glMapBufferARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, GL_READ_WRITE );
    }
    else
    {
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_uiVertBufferHandle );

        //make sure our buffer exists
        buffer1 = glMapBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE );
    }

    if( buffer1 )
    {
        //collection of all our data
        void* buffer2 = new char[ (m_uiNumVerts)*sizeof(VertexFormat) ];
        memset( buffer2, 0, (m_uiNumVerts)*sizeof(VertexFormat) );
        memcpy( buffer2, buffer1, (m_uiNumVerts - uiIncrement)*sizeof(VertexFormat)     );

        //create a new buffer
        //unsigned uiNewHandle;

        if (GLEW_ARB_vertex_shader)
        {
            //allocate our new storage space, and store our data in there
            glBufferDataARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, (m_uiNumVerts*sizeof(VertexFormat)), buffer2, GL_DYNAMIC_READ );

            //lock our buffer
            //void* buffer2 = glMapBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, GL_READ_WRITE );    

            //unlock our buffer2
            //if( glUnmapBufferARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB ) == GL_FALSE )
            //  return false;
            //}

            //reset what we are bound to
            glBindBufferARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0 );
        }
        else
        {
            //allocate our new storage space, and store our data in there
            glBufferDataARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, (m_uiNumVerts*sizeof(VertexFormat)), buffer2, GL_DYNAMIC_READ );

            //reset what we are bound to
            glBindBufferARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0 );
        }

        //delete our buffer
        free( buffer2 );

        //Unmap our currently mapped buffer
        glUnmapBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER );

    return true;
}

unsigned int CVertexBuffer::AddVerts(const VERTEX_ANIMATED* pVerts, unsigned int iNumVerts)
{
    //Save the location to copy to
    unsigned int uiVertLocation = m_uiVertsUsed;

    m_uiVertsUsed += iNumVerts;

    if(m_uiVertsUsed > m_uiNumVerts)
    {
        IncreaseVerts(m_uiVertsUsed - m_uiNumVerts);
    }

    if(GLEW_ARB_vertex_program)
    {
        //bind the buffer we're gonna mess with
        glBindBufferARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, m_uiVertBufferHandle );

        //get the pointer position where we can add verts
        void* pPositionBuffer = glMapBufferARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, GL_READ_WRITE     );

        //now copy into our memory spot
        //which we need to move to the right position
        memcpy( ((char*)pPositionBuffer) + ( uiVertLocation*sizeof(VertexFormat) ), pVerts, iNumVerts*sizeof(VertexFormat));

        //now stop mapping
        glUnmapBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB);
    }
    else
    {
        //bind the buffer we're gonna mess with
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_uiVertBufferHandle );

        //get the pointer position where we can add verts
        void* pPositionBuffer = glMapBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE );

        //now copy into our memory spot
        //which we need to move to the right position
        memcpy( ((char*)pPositionBuffer) + ( uiVertLocation*sizeof(VertexFormat) ), pVerts, iNumVerts*sizeof(VertexFormat));

        //now stop mapping
        glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    }

    return uiVertLocation;
}
```

I am assuming my error comes from how I am initializing my data or how I pass my data to the shader.

Here is a simple call to my shader program creation it takes in a vertex shader file name and a fragment shader file name then a variable for main variables that wish to be specified such as "position, normals, texCoords"

```
CreateProgram( "animTriangle.vp",
               "animTriangle.fp",
               5,
               VERTEX_ATTRIB, "vVertexPos",
               NORMAL_ATTRIB, "vVertexNormal",
               TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB0, "vTexCoord",
               COLOR_ATTRIB, "vBlendWeights",
               COLOR2_ATTRIB, "vBoneIndices" );
```

in side this function I do a parameter parsing after have created and compiled the shader program

```
 //make sure to use our program to setup our handles
glUseProgram( m_uiProgramHandle );

//start from this parameter
va_start( parseList, szFragmentShaderName );

//read in number of variables if any
uiNum = va_arg( parseList, unsigned );

//for loop through our attribute pairs
int enumType = 0;
for( unsigned x = 0; x < uiNum; ++x )
{
    //specify our attribute locations
    enumType = va_arg( parseList, int );
    char* name = va_arg( parseList, char* );
    glBindAttribLocation( m_uiProgramHandle, enumType, name );
}

//end our list parsing
va_end( parseList );
```

here is my variable list at the beginning of my vertex shader

```
in vec3 vVertexPos;     // position
in vec3 vVertexNormal;  // normal
in vec2 vTexCoord;      // texture coordinate....
in vec4 vBlendWeights;  // the weights pull of the related bone
in ivec4 vBoneIndices;  // the indicators of which bones we are influenced by
```

here is my vertex stride

```
 //set which vertices we will be using
 glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_uiVertBufferHandle );

 //enable these vertex attributes
 glEnableVertexAttribArray( VERTEX_ATTRIB );
 glEnableVertexAttribArray( NORMAL_ATTRIB );
 glEnableVertexAttribArray( TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB0 );
 glEnableVertexAttribArray( COLOR_ATTRIB );
 glEnableVertexAttribArray( COLOR2_ATTRIB );

 //specify our vertex attribute
 glVertexAttribPointer( VERTEX_ATTRIB, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( VERTEX_ANIMATED ), BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );

 //specify our normal attribute
 glVertexAttribPointer( NORMAL_ATTRIB, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( VERTEX_ANIMATED ), BUFFER_OFFSET(12) );

 //specify our texture attribute
 glVertexAttribPointer( TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( VERTEX_ANIMATED ), BUFFER_OFFSET(24) );

 //specify our bone weight attribute location
 glVertexAttribPointer( COLOR_ATTRIB, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( VERTEX_ANIMATED ), BUFFER_OFFSET(32) );

 //specify our bone indice attribute location
 glVertexAttribPointer( COLOR2_ATTRIB, 4, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( VERTEX_ANIMATED ), BUFFER_OFFSET(48) );
```

now I can load static models just fine. When I load my animated models I get like half the model or half the model with some chunks missing on that half. I have worked with DirectX before and I only ever came across that issue when the gpu was reading my buffers in correctly.

If you guys would like any more info let me know. I been on this weird issue for almost 2 weeks and would really like to learn my problem.

Comment: How are you passing the bone matrices to the shader?

Comment: in the shader it looks like this
/
    uniform mat4 mAnimPose[40];
/
in the .cpp this is how i pass it
/
    glUniformMatrix4fv( glGetUniformLocation( pCurShader->GetShaderProgramHandle(), "mAnimPose" ), pCurBones.size(), GL_FALSE, (float*)(&pCurBones[0]) );
/
but currently in the shader i do not use them just to test the rest of the model so i basically set the verts to be multiplied only by the model view projection matrix that matrice works because its the one i use in my static model shader

Comment: sorry i am no good with this stack over flow comment code syntax X_X

Comment: Alright, I guess that's not the issue then. Did you remember to increase the stride/size of your vertex attributes to account for the weight/indices?

Comment: it wont let me add that much lol I have added it to the normal question at the bottom

Comment: Is `VERTEX_ANIMATED` synonymous with `VertexFormat`? Also if some of the model is missing, but the rest looks OK, maybe the problem lies with your index buffer.

Comment: Yeah VertexFormat is Vertex_Animated. sorry in the engine I have different vertex formats for stackoverflow i just converted everything to what my issue is with. My index buffer loads identical to the format above used on loading the vertex buffer except its just using unsigned ints.

Comment: Could it be something relaxed to openGL and windows 8? because my build do behave a little bit different from my laptop and my new windows 8 desktop. Maybe its my openGL libs?

Comment: Is it legal to leave a buffer mapped, while you call glBufferData? I would assume it isn't, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you may have forgotten to initialize `NORMAL_ATTRIB` in your code. Your call to `CreateProgram (...)` does not include an association of `NORMAL_ATTRIB` with `vVertexNormal` in your vertex shader.

If your vertex shader requires the vertex normal for animation purposes and you have not correctly hooked up this vertex pointer to the appropriate attribute slot, then the results will be undefined.

Likewise, the problem may also be due to `NORMAL_ATTRIB` aliasing to another one of your attributes due to leaving it uninitialized. For instance, vertex attribute 0 is usually position, if you leave `NORMAL_ATTRIB` uninitialized in this code you may be re-defining your vertex position pointer with the normal pointer.

Comment: I do this step but my issue i THINK is my boneIndices are not proper I figured it might have been my vertex stride. do you mind looking at this one on one @Andon M. Coleman? because my bones are fine within the animation but i cannot seem to get the skin to attach properly

Answer (score 0):

My overall issue had turned out to be with my draw call. I was specifying the number of primitive triangles to be drawn rather than the number of indices which would just be my "triangle count * 3".

This would explain why some of the model would show up but it would be chunked up.